# Setting up android with ADT Bundle

Tags: android, adt

I am trying to setting up android with ADT Bundle on win7. I have installed the package, however I cannot find the "Android SDK Manager". This option isn't available when I open the "window" tab as mentioned [**here**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html).

I am an absolute beginner here, and not sure if there something else I need to install?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK is already included in the package. The folder, adt-bundle-windows-x64/x86 should consist of 2 additional folders namely eclipse and sdk, and the SDK Manager (greenish Android icon, which you are searching for).

You can run it from there itself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the Android SDK installed, but now you will need to install the ADT plugin to Eclipse so that the two will be able to talk.. Do this by doing the following in Eclipse:

Help -> Install New Software -> Add

Name:     `Android`
Location: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

OK -> When Loaded, Check (Developer Tools) -> Next -> Accept -> Etc. -> Restart Eclipse

The next time eclipse is run it will prompt you to setup the Android SDK where you will need to point it to the install directory of your SDK.

**EDIT**

Go to [this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for Android Developers and click on the Blue download button. This will download a ZIP which when extracted will contain a copy of the Android SDK as well as Eclipse which is already configured.

Let me know if this one works or not. Happy coding!

Comment: tried this also, got the following error "Unable to read repository at https:/dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https:/dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Host name may not be null" :(

Comment: Apparntly it was an issue with my proxy. It works now, thanks.

Comment: Awesome, if I helped you out, be sure to mark the question as Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Again, after  runing the Eclipse appears.

Java Virtual Machine Laucher. Error: Could not open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ECLIPSE...

In the Setting Up the ADT Bundle,  in the last paragraph says Caution:, this is my problem.
How change the path manually

**This is an old path, and as I can not change it, that stops here**

Setting Up the ADT Bundle

The ADT Bundle provides everything you need to start developing apps, including a version of the Eclipse IDE with built-in ADT (Android Developer Tools) to streamline your Android app development. If you haven't already, go download the Android ADT Bundle. (If you downloaded the SDK Tools only, for use with an existing IDE, you should instead read Setting Up an Existing IDE.)

Install the SDK and Eclipse IDE
 1.Unpack the ZIP file (named adt-bundle-.zip) and save it to an appropriate location, such as a "Development" directory in your home directory.
 2.Open the adt-bundle-/eclipse/ directory and launch eclipse.

That's it! The IDE is already loaded with the Android Developer Tools plugin and the SDK is ready to go. To start developing, read Building Your First App.

Caution: Do not move any of the files or directories from the adt-bundle- directory. If you move the eclipse or sdk directory, ADT will not be able to locate the SDK and you'll need to manually update the ADT preferences.

Tank you

Answer (score -1):

Better download [ADT bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) provided in Android Developer site in that both Eclipse and Android SDK come in a bundle

after downloading just install which all API levels u need in Android SDK

Comment: Question is I think regarding issue in ADT bundle itself.